# The phrase "in relationship" with zero article

Tags: zero-article

Context: "God wanted to be in relationship with His people."

Is it okay not to use an article before "relationship?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is somewhat odd.  It would seem to be a technical expression dealing with the nature of the divine. Humanity is in a state that we call *relationship* with that entity that we call *God*.  We understand that "relationship" doesn't have its normal meaning.  Compare:

> Like it or not, we are all asked to be in relationship with loss and grief. (Huff. Post)

However, most examples that I can find of these words are simple errors or typos.  If you just mean "God loves humans and wants humans to love God" then "in a relationship" is natural and normal.